# Backbone wait for model to be initialized

Tags: backbone.js

I have a problem that is causing trouble all over my app. I have a master model that instantiates a number of models and collections inside its initialize method. Some of those need to use attributes of the master model via master.get("whatever_attribute") but since this instantiations happen before the initialize method for that master object is done, the master object is still undefined.

Note that this master model's attributes are not fetched from a server but rather passed as options so using the "sync" event is not an option without some awkward overriding of the sync method.

Here's some code. I hope I'm not missing anything. Had to modify quite a bit to make it clear.

```
(function() {
    var App;

    App.Connection = function(config) {
        App.account = new Account(config);
        delete App.Connection;
        return App;
    };

    Mixins = {
        sync: function (method, model, options) {
            console.debug('App.account: %o',App.account); // -> undefined
            App.account.users.at(1).get("signature"); // -> undefined
            App.account.get("token"); // -> undefined
        }
    }

    var Account = Backbone.Model.extend({
        initialize: function() {
            this.users = new Users();
        }
    });
    var User = Backbone.Model.extend({
        sync: Mixins.sync
    });
    var Users = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: User
    });

}).call(this);

appInstance = new App.Connection({
    "token": "675938hu5gc3ntxe8fg69m8snbvdh",
    "user": {
        "signature": "vn7we8bvy8wbefhivbfsbcdfjbvdfsbv"
    }
});
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: I agree, code, please. I have a similar situation, but I just pass the “master” object in to the initialisers of the other objects and there’s no problem with it being undefined.

Comment: You have control of your `Master.initialize()` so why no just initialize the `Master` object in the first lines and initialize the inner-objects after that?

Comment: There's some code. Didn't include it before bc it was late and had to modify a lot to simplify it for this post. Note that I return a simple "App" object because, in the real application I need that to hold a bunch of other data. Thanks.